# How can I take the elevation out of a json object so I am left with longitude and latitude, but not altitude?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a use case for importing coordinates into a system. The coordinates are provided to me in a JSON format with each point having latitude, longitude, and elevation (sometimes). I'm using @jq to format the json file and remove everything but the coordinates. I have tried and googled methods to cycle through the array and remove any elevations, but no luck. I'm currently manually removing them using vim and reading through the coordinates. I would like to script it so I can use the system's API to fully automate receiving the coordinates and applying them to the system.

TIA.

The data looks like this when it arrives:
{ [ 48.2725225, 12.6538725, 595.2270812 ], [ 48.2725226, 12.6654544 ] }

I need it to be formatted like this without the elevations:
{ [ 48.2725225, 12.6538725 ], [ 48.2725226, 12.6654544 ] }

I've run through multiple data filters and wrote loops to iterate through each element of the array and remove the 3rd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input

```bash
{ [ 48.2725225, 12.6538725, 595.2270812 ], [ 48.2725226, 12.6654544 ] }
```

is not valid JSON. Curly object braces `{}` [demand](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) a comma-separated list of key-value pairs with a colon `:` in between.

---

If instead you had an array of arrays (both enclosed within square brackets `[]`) like this:

```bash
[ [ 48.2725225, 12.6538725, 595.2270812 ], [ 48.2725226, 12.6654544 ] ]
```

you could use `map` on the outer array to individually process each inner array. That processing could then be to slice the array, reducing it to its first two elements `.[:2]`:

```
map(.[:2])
```

```json
[ [48.2725225,12.6538725], [48.2725226,12.6654544] ]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nAMnzmPLVJO)

---

If, however, you only have a stream of arrays like this (notice the lack of braces **and** commas compared to the outer array from above):

```bash
[ 48.2725225, 12.6538725, 595.2270812 ] [ 48.2725226, 12.6654544 ]
```

you can directly proceed with the slicing, no outer mapping is needed:

```bash
.[:2]
```

```json
[48.2725225,12.6538725] [48.2725226,12.6654544]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_slTYoMpnxS)

---

Also notice that the output format provided here matches the input format (outer array or stream). Of course, you can convert one into another if you want (see the `--slurp` option or the item iterator `.[]` for that).

If your input format is neither, you'd have to apply other means to turn it into one of these.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is definitely the path forward for this.